# Kotlin create a query result to parse github repositories

Tags: kotlin, retrofit

I am using the Retrofit library for my REST calls. How i will insert this json query to my code inside the question marks?

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?sort=stars&order=desc&q=created:2013-01-01?

This is my code in kotlin :

```
class SearchRepository(val apiService: GithubApiService) {

fun searchUsers(??????): io.reactivex.Observable<Result> {
        return apiService.search(query = "?????")
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to pass json into function as an argument?

Comment: what about this return apiService.search(query = "?????") what i must pust inside exclamations?

Comment: @redSparrow I have just written some thing like this recently. [Here is api interface](https://github.com/joshuaavalon/GitHubApiDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/joshuaavalon/githubapidemo/service/api/RepositoryApi.kt).

Comment: Well, it depends on how you implemented the `GithubApiService`.

Comment: I guess, he got the implementation [here](https://github.com/segunfamisa/retrofit-kotlin-sample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/segunfamisa/kotlin/samples/retrofit/data/kotlin/GithubApiService.kt). Still it's not clear what is asked here.